# Flash boot.img without using fastboot USB

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, boot, fastboot

So I've recently rooted my phone and tried a ROM or two. I find it really handy that you can use TWRP recovery to install another ROM from the SD card, you don't need to have it connected to a PC.

However, on my device (HTC One S) I need to flash a different boot.img file for every ROM as well, so I still need to hook my phone up to my PC to switch ROMs. If I don't do this, it just gets stuck on the loading screen. Then I must use the command

```
fastboot flash boot boot.img
```

from the folder where boot.img is located.

Is it possible to flash this boot image with TWRP or any other way without using fastboot over USB?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What needs to be done is to bundle the boot.img and construct a new zip file suitable for flashing via ClockworkMod or TWRP.

**Pre-requisites**:

- a Linux environment that has the usual development packages, such as Java installed. (*It can also **apply** to other platforms, just be careful that the instructions here indicating the path used below, uses a forward slash `/`, so flip that around to be a back slash `\` for Windows environment especially!*)
- adb command line tool installed.
- `testsign.jar' [tool](https://code.google.com/p/zen-droid/downloads/detail?name=testsign.jar&can=2&q=), for signing the zip file so that the recovery can authenticate and verify it is a valid archive otherwise recovery will report *corrupt archive* or similar.
- `update-binary` command line [application](http://wiki.opticaldelusion.org/wiki/Update-binary), that is internal for usage with the flashable script. (This can be found with **any** flashable zip, the important thing is to extract that binary and deposited in the structure of the directory as shown)
- zip command line tool.

Assuming your directory is called **workdir**, for discussion, lets call this the working directory, copy the `boot.img` into that directory, and create the following directory structure - `META-INF/com/google/android`, this is important! And within the `META-INF/com/google/android`, copy the binary application called `update-binary` into that directory. So the directory structure should be like this:

```
+ workdir/
     +
     |
     +--+ boot.img
     |
     |
     +--+ META-INF/
              +
              |
              +--+ com/
                    +
                    |
                    +--+ google/
                           +
                           |
                           +--+ android/
                                   +
                                   |
                                   +--> update-binary
                                   |
                                   +--> updater-script
```

As for the `updater-script`, copy the contents of the following below:

```
ui_print("Please wait, boot.img being flashed...");
show_progress(0.1, 0);
assert(package_extract_file("boot.img", "/tmp/boot.img"),
       write_raw_image("/tmp/boot.img", "boot"),
       delete("/tmp/boot.img"));
show_progress(0.1, 10);
ui_print("It is now safe to reboot! :)");
```

***Remember:*** Do not get confused here, the updater-script as shown, should be left alone and as-is, so do not try flip the forward-slash to a back slash if doing this under Windows environment.

Go back to the parent of the directory structure, i.e. outside of **workdir** and do the following, we're going to create a zip file from this:

`zip -r my_custom_flashable_boot_unsigned.zip workdir/` which is a recursive function, this will zip up everything into the file called **my_custom_flashable_boot_unsigned.zip**.

Finally, to sign the zip file, issue this:

```
java -classpath testsign.jar testsign my_custom_flashable_boot_unsigned.zip my_custom_flashable_boot_signed.zip
```

Then its a matter of pushing that across the SDCard as in `adb push my_custom_flashable_boot_signed.zip /sdcard/` and manually go into recovery and specify that zip archive (i.e. **my_custom_flashable_boot_signed.zip**)  in which it will perform the flashing for you.

Comment: Nice, I like to create stuff myself so excellent instructions. It's not a point that I'll need my computer for this, because I can just get flashable boot zips for all my ROMs on a folder of my SD card, which will lead to the situation I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `flash_image` binary, then you can do it on device via terminal emulator (flash boot, then the rest using recovery).

Syntax: `flash_image boot /sdcard/boot.img`

Self Promotion Time

I have an app that provides a GUI for the binary.  Find it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.liamwli.flash).

If you don't have that binary, it can be installed (Google it - you have to download it then copy it to the `/system/bin` folder.

This doesn't work on all devices, however it's the only way that springs to mind.

Comment: If I understand well, the terminal emulator is just a regular app that you run while your phone is booted in normal mode? Will it not give problems flashing boot while the OS is running?

Comment: @MarioDeSchaepmeester The phone only uses boot while it boots ;)

Comment: Have had to downvote it, as `flash_image` has a requirement to be copied and invoked from the handset using `adb shell`, [documentation](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/wiki/flash_image) (*may I add, you failed to provide the linky!) is asking to remount the SDCard with exec bit set (*bad idea*) and requires root i.e. `su`, further to that, the "self-promotion" in relation to your app, in euros, where I come from, is 6,09 euros which is pricey... **fastboot** is the norm, CM has their own quirky ways, - what's different with `fastboot` and `flash_image`?

Comment: Also the binary can be used without a computer.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to flash this boot image with TWRP [...]?

rename the file **boot.emmc.win** and place it in `TWRP/BACKUPS/` (create new folder). restore the backup from usual TWRP menu