# Device boots normally, but cannot enter recovery or fastboot

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, unbricking, fastboot, bootloader

I have secondhand Vodafone Smart Tab 4G. It seems to me that previous owner messed something up.

The device boots normally but I cannot enter either bootloader, fastboot, or recovery. I have tried HW combinations, RebootManager software, and ADB commands. I would like to restore the device to factory defaults, but I have no idea how to do that.

I can connect by ADB:

```
~ $ adb devices
List of devices attached 
1b54ef6a    device
```

But if I try either `adb reboot bootloader`, or `adb reboot recovery`, the device hangs on "Powered by Android" logo. If I try `adb reboot fastboot` it just normally reboots.

Trying to restore factory defaults from settings or running system update, the device reboots and hangs on "Powered by Android" logo.

Also the device is rooted.

Comment: I've faced a same kind of situation on a MTK device try just to re-flash the **recovery.img and boot.img** file and follow the Instructions to **flash recovery without fastboot from the link below** <https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36265/flash-boot-img-without-using-fastboot-usb> this will surely fix your problem and you can access your recovery after this

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @Asu unfortunately no and I no longer own the device.